# Dynamic display the records with label

Tags: custom-field, dynamic, label

I have different fieldset for recordtype. On click of recordtype i am getting all the fields and doing soql and getting the result into a list and passing the list to a VF page. Now I need to display all the soql result as i don't know which all fields been soql, so i need to do a dynamic for loop on VF page. I also want display the label of the field. How can we achieve it. Please guide me.

My Vf page

```
<apex:actionFunction id="actionF" name="callme" action="{!accountInformations}" reRender="accLs" >
     <apex:param name="myids" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:outputPanel id="accLs" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!accList}" var="acc" >
       <!-- Here I want to display all the fields with their label. -->
    </apex:repeat >
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the solution given in this blog http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/visualforce-field-sets.html

Answer (score 0):

This might suit your requirement

```
<apex:actionFunction id="actionF" name="callme" action="{!accountInformations}" reRender="accLs" >
     <apex:param name="myids" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>

 <apex:outputPanel id="accLs" >
     <apex:repeat value="{!accList}" var="acc" >
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.YOUR_FIELDSET_NAME}" var="currField"> 
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">{!currField.label}</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc[currField]}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:repeat>
     </apex:repeat >
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Where is this dynamically changing depending upon recordtype?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a list of Schema.FieldSetMember and access it in VF page. Something like this.

```
List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldList;
if(recordType == something)
 fieldList = SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.somethingFieldSet.getFields(); 
else if(recordType == somethingelse)
 fieldList = SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.somethingElseFieldSet.getFields();
```

Now loop through this fieldList in your VF page before `apex:repeat`. To get the label names, use `getLabel()` like this.

```
for(Schema.FieldSetMember fm : fieldList)
{
    System.debug('value'+fm.getLabel());
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?